# std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& , ClassName& )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I checked in the internet but could not find something suitable.

How it is possible to have a main like this (original main):

```
 int main()
    {
        Image left;
        std::ifstream ifs("left.txt");
        ifs >> left;
        ifs.close();
        waitForKey("cout << left");
        std::cout << left;
    }
```

And try to make like this (my decoding):

```
//m_pixel is a member that holds a single char
//m_H = height
//m_W = width
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ClassName& image)
{
    image.m_pixel = new Pixel*[image.m_H];

    for (int i = 0; i < image.m_H; i++)
        image.m_pixel[i] = new Pixel[image.m_W];
}
```

Like how am I suppose to insert the 'is' into the image if I do not know for example the height and width? How can I know them? And how than I can insert the character of the 'is' inside the image? In short, how to decode this code?

Comment: use a `std::vector`.  It lets you store an unknown number of elements.

Comment: Well, everything depends on how the image is stored inside the file. That's what file formats are for.

Comment: the information on the height and width has to come from somewhere, either stored as header in the file or you just read what is in the file and count number of cols&rows while reading the file

Comment: You probably want an `std::istream` for input rather than `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously when you dump your image, you need to start by dumping the sizes:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ClassName& image)
{
    os << image.m_H << " " << image.m_W;
    // Dump the rest as before
    return os;
}
```

Then read them again and then the rest of your data:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ClassName& image)
{
    is >> image.m_H >> image.m_W;
    image.m_pixel = new Pixel*[image.m_H];

    for (int i = 0; i < image.m_H; ++i)
    {
        image.m_pixel[i] = new Pixel[image.m_W];
        for (int j = 0; j < image.m_W; ++j)
        {
             is >> image.m_pixel[i][j];
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

But as @NathanOliver said, use a `std::vector<Pixel>`.